# How to edit/delete single row items in a table on my own menu page

Tags: plugins, php, admin, database

I have successfully created a wp-LINKS-list-table that displays the output of WP's core "Links" table in the WP Dashboard, and I have it displaying on a menu page I created.  Step 1 accomplished!

But now I would like to be able to have the single row edit/delete (database) functionality just like the Links page. Right now I can edit/delete the links, but it's just adding/removing items from the actual links database table. I'm assuming that I not only have to create a different database table for my own queries, but I need to process my pages outside of the WordPress core as well. Right?

Or is there a core WP functionality that I can use to edit/delete my own table items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress allows you to use a class called [wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

```
Here is an example of how you would use it
function add_to_db() {
global $wpdb;
$your_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "wp-LINKS-list-table";
$the_value = '123';
$wpdb->insert( $your_table_name, array('column_name' => $the_value,));
```

this will insert 123 into the column_name. You can read more [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_rows)

Note: If you are creating a menu page that reflects the tables similar to the wordpress tables there is another class you can use to help you. It is called [WP_List_Table](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table) I would suggest reading that and getting the [Custom List Table Example Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-list-table-example/) it is very helpful showing examples of using WP_List_Table.